# Different Groupings for different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I don't know weather it is possible or not..
i have a table with 4 columns for example

```
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4
------------------------------------
O1       O1       P1       P1
O2       O1       P3       P1
O2       O2       P4       P1
O1       O3       P2       P2
O3       O3       P5       P3
```

i need a output like

```
Col     Col1Col3     Col2Col4 
------------------------------------
O1       2              1
O2       2              1
O3       1              2
```

Result should be count(Col3) group by Col1 and Count(Col4) group by Col2.
Can this be possible without using "UNION" as i have 5 different groupings to be done.
Can anyone help me on this...

Comment: _"i have a table with 3 columns for example
Col1     Col2     Col3     Col4"_

Comment: Sry Tim, its a typo :)

Comment: Looking at the extensive code behind your question, I have a hint: You can make stackoverflow format your code

Comment: A UNION solution will be easy to write, understand and maintain. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    col1, Col1Col3, Col2Col4 
From(
    select col1,count(Col3)  Col1Col3 
    from YourTable
    group by Col1
)x join 
(
    select col2, Count(Col4)  Col2Col4 
    from YourTable
    group by Col2
)y on x.Col1=y.col2
```

OR

```
select 
    col1, 
    SUM(c13) Col1Col3, 
    SUM(c24) Col2Col4
from(
    select Col1, 1 c13, 0 c24 From YourTable
    union all
    select Col2, 0 c13, 1 c24 From YourTable
)x
group by col1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Techdo, but i have to do 5 other groupings in the same query. Here i have to use multiple joins as your process. Is there any other way to minimize no. of lines of code?

Comment: The queries are not equivalent. The first only show groups available in both col1 and col2

Comment: Yeah... it's because of the join. I wrote the query for the given sample data.